# Add or replace data files to existing PyInstaller exe (--onefile)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I use PyInstaller to package a one-file executable. The task I have been assigned is to create webservice that can return the PyInstaller executable as an attachment.

Depending on the user that is logged in I need to interchange a user-data file inside the executable. I know I can do this by rebuilding the executable on every request, but since the executables per user will be identical only differing by the data file mentioned above and since the build takes up both a time and processing power, I was wondering if it is possible to post-edit the PyInstaller executable and then either add or replace the user-data file contained in the .exe file.

In other words use a PyInstaller executable as template for the final user executables.

**EDIT:** This is what I have tried until now:

```
>>> from PyInstaller.loader import carchive
>>> arc = carchive.CArchive(path_to_exe)
>>> arc.add(('README.rst','C:\\temp\\pyinstaller-2.0\\README.rst',1,'s'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\carchive.py", line 245, in add
    self.lib.write(s)
IOError: File not open for writing
```

Clearly this is goes nowhere cause opening an executable with carchive is appearantly always a read-only operation.

Best Regards
Jakob Simon-Gaarde

Comment: I have edited my post so you can see what I have tried.

Comment: Looking through the source code, you can't change an existing archive, unless you're prepared to rewrite parts of the `PyInstaller` library.

Comment: What exactly is the "user-data" file you need to change? If it's a fixed-length thing, and assuming `PyInstaller` doesn't compress or checksum the final `.exe` file, you might be able to hand-patch the binary.